# discord.py - How can I add an role to an specific member?

Tags: python, discord.py

I wanted to make an event that when someone deletes "Owner", it adds back the role by the persons name, heres an attemp (didnt work obviously)

Is that possible?

**Attempt / Example:**

```
  @bot.event
  async def on_server_role_delete(role, *, ctx = None, user: discord.Member):
      client = bot
      author = user.name("SlimeYT")
      permissions = discord.Permissions(permissions=2146958847)
      await client.create_role(author.server, name="Member", permissions=permissions, colour=discord.Colour(0xb400ff))
      await bot.add_roles(author, discord.utils.get(ctx.message.author.server.roles, name="Member"))
```

Comment: Read the Event Reference for [`on_server_role_delete`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_server_role_delete).  The only information the event gives you is the `Role` that was deleted. Is `Owner` supposed to be the owner of the bot or the server? Both can be determined programmatically without roles.

Comment: i wanted to add to an ´User´no the owner of the server

Comment: The discord servers are sending your bot a message saying "Hey, this role that you can see was deleted: <Role Object>".  Your bot turns that object into a `discord.Role` object and calls your `on_server_role_delete` coroutine with it.  It doesn't know anything about your coroutine.  There is no way for you to communicate to your bot that you want it to pass extra arguments.  If you want to resolve a `user` object, you must do it inside the body of your coroutine.

Comment: Like, I wanted to do something like, if an role for example "Mod" gets deleted or removed, it adds back to the member.name

Comment: You could potentially loop over `role.members` to get assign the new role to everyone who had the old role.

Comment: how can I do that

Comment: @SlimeYT Please don't add FIXED to the title. Accepting the answer is enough to mark it as answered (it will appear differently in the list of questions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way that you can check the name of the deleted role and then assign a hard-coded user a new, identical role.

```
IMMORTAL_ROLES = ["Owner", "Admin"]
OWNER_ID = "123"

@bot.event
async def on_server_role_delete(role):
    if role.name not in IMMORTAL_ROLES:
        return
    new_role = await bot.create_role(role.server, name=role.name, permissions=role.permissions,
                                     colour=role.colour, hoist=role.hoist, 
                                     mentionable=role.mentionable)
    member = role.server.get_member(OWNER_ID)  # You could also use get_member_named
    await bot.add_roles(member, new_role)
```